# Несоответствие размеров кнопок при добавлении текста разной длины

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

У меня есть `button` и `a`, они должны быть одинакового размера. Если текст достаточно длинный, то всё в порядке, но если короткий, то размеры разные. Подскажите, почему это происходит и как это можно исправить?

```css
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #FFC0CB;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div>
    <p>Короткий текст</p>
    <button class="button">
      <span>Да</span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <span>Да</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Средний текст</p>
    <button class="button">
      <span>Сохранить</span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <span>Сохранить</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тегу `button` браузер по дефолту прописывает свойство `box-sizing: border-box;`. Измените его или добавьте к тегу `a`.